# In Rails, how do I display a string value from matching database value with id in HelperClass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have states stored in my database with numeric values... as in:

```
["Alabama", "1"],
["Alaska", "2"],
["Arizona", "3"],
["Arkansas", "4"],
ETC....
```

When I want to display "Alaska" because the number 2 is being output, how do I do this?

I tried something like this in my controller:

```
def show
  @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
  @state = contact.location_state
end
```

And have the following in my "show.html.erb":

```
<%= @state %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case you have to deal with an array of arrays you can get the specific number in the second position of every array accessing to it, with the index `[1]`:

```
places = [
  ["Alabama", "1"],
  ["Alaska", "2"],
  ["Arizona", "3"],
  ["Arkansas", "4"]
]

p places[0][1]
# => "1"
```

If you have a single one, you don't need to specify the precise array inside the main array of arrays, just with:

```
place = ["Alabama", "1"]
p place[1]
# => "1"
```

If you're sending the `@state` object and want to work with it in your views you can iterate and show the second value corresponding to the number you want to show:

```
places.each{|place| p place[1]}
# => "1"
# => "2"
# => "3"
# => "4"
```

Comment: So if I'm trying to display "Alaska" for example... from the id stored in the database "2" can I do this?

@state = places.each{|place| p where.place[1] == location_state}

location_state being what is stored in my database and is equal to "2"...

Comment: Do you want to find the record when you know the id?, you can do `Place.find(2)`, if places is your model where you're getting those values as array.

Comment: I have the number stored in the database... And I'm already able to grab that... I just can't get "Alaska" to display so the user sees "Alaska" instead of "2"...

Comment: What do you get when you do the query?, can you do `@place = Place.find(2)`, and then in your view `<%= @place.name %>`?, name or whatever is the attribute you use to store "Alaska".

Comment: I get "2" when I query for "contact.location_state". The states are in my ContactsHelper file...

So I don't think I can do the @place = Place.find(2), right?

Comment: Thank you for helping me work through this by the way!

Comment: You're welcome, if I've helped you, consider accepting the answer, I'll try to do the same to help you.

Comment: I'll accept it soon... I still can't get my exact answer :( But I think you've pointed me in the right direction...

Comment: If you wanna give more details, and as we can't use the stack chat, maybe Gitter or Slack.

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure what else to give...

I'll try mentioning it a different way...

In my database, I have a table for Contacts... There is a column named "locations_state"... values stored in this column are numbers 1-51 for the different states. I can get those values, but I am having a hard time matching those number values to my state array in my ContactsHelper so that I can display the state text... So my example was, one contact has the state "Alaska" stored as "2" but when I get the value from the database, I can't turn the "2" back into the text "Alaska"... Is that making sense? ha

Comment: If you do `@contacts = Contact.all`, you'll get all the records, this way you can use the variable and inspect it in your view `<%= @contacts.inspect %>` and to see in which way you can get those two values (name, and number) that you need.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!